# git annex get unable to establish SSL connection with dropbox

Tags: git, ssl, github, git-annex

I was try to build and compile a project called [RoboComp](https://github.com/robocomp/robocomp) on github

When I try to download some package using command git annex get ., it failed for it can't establish SSL connection with https://dropboxusercontent.com/s/..., I find it confusing.

I have checked my system time to be correct and shut down all my proxy or firewall. Nothing works.

I really hope somebody can help me fix this.

I have issued this problem [here](https://github.com/robocomp/robocomp/issues/16). See for more detail.

Here is a snapshot of that.[image]

Comment: Thx. But can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the GFW in China or the network limit at university or company. Using a VPN will solve the problem.